# Index hints cannot be specified within a schema-bound object

Tags: sql-server, view, alter

I receive this error message when I altered my view
"Index hints cannot be specified within a schema-bound object."

How can I do for solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us your `ALTER VIEW` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Indexed views cannot be altered; they have to be dropped and re-created.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and thats because you are having WITH SCHEMABINDING option after ALTER VIEW vw_MyView. Remove that clause and it will allow you to alter. Although I have dropped and recreated the view but only worked after I removed WITH SCHEMABINDING option.